# EventListener that triggers when text input, but NOT when input is deleted

Tags: javascript, validation, addeventlistener

**Background**:

I'm adding event listeners to a HTML form, that check if the input in each field is valid. For example:

```
inputElement.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        if (!isValid(input.value)) {
            input.setCustomValidity("Input is invalid");
        } else {
            input.setCustomValidity("");
        }
});
```

However, the form field in question is not mandatory - the user can submit the form with the field empty, but they can't submit it with invalid input.

**Problem**:

If the user submits the form without ever touching that input (leaving it blank) the `"input"` event never occurs, and the form can be submitted. (Good)

If the user enters incorrect input and submits the form, they get a warning message `"input is invalid"`. (Good)

But, if they enter invalid input, get the warning message, and then *delete* the input, the warning message will appear and the form will now submit. (Bad)

This happens because the act of deleting the input triggers the `input` event.

**Progress**:

I've tried using the `textInput` event instead but I get the same behaviour. I've checked for [other available events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) but I can't see one that would fix this problem.

I *could* make it work by modifying my `isValid` function to return `true` if given an empty string, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. The reason being: I've simplified the example here but in reality that function is actually `isValidServiceId` and technically an empty string is not a valid service id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your conditional logic to say "If *the input is populated* **and** invalid", rather than just "If the input is invalid"...

```
inputElement.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  if (input.value.length && !isValid(input.value)) {
    input.setCustomValidity("Input is invalid");
  } else {
    input.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```